# website displayed differently on localhost and when uploaded to a server

Tags: php, html, css, web

I have designed a responsive website using php. its mainly html but i have included some php functions and saved all the pages. I have 2 style sheets 1 for the responsive and the other for the normal view. I tested the complete site in my localhost (wamp server) and didn't see any issues but when i uploaded the website online, the complete design seems messed up. All files including the css are uploaded correctly.

the fonts are too small, the alignments are not correct and the site seems to be shirked, but the same site shows everything correctly when tested in my local host.

Can someone please tell me what is the problem?

Comment: If you can please post the online site url. So we can have a clear idea. I guess most probably 404 error is there.

Comment: @CanGeliş just checked all the paths are correct. when i downloaded the same copy and added to the local host and worked perfect. firebug doesn't show any error either.

Comment: @NewDeveloper i completely removed the website and restored the old website back. Il try to upload it to a different place.

Comment: is the local PHP version the same as the one on the server?

Comment: Check your zoom level in your browser

Comment: @Mooseman yep.. its the exact same copy.

Answer (score 2):

1. Ensure all files (especially CSS and JS) are loaded. You can check this for example by using [Firebug Net panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel#Request_List). Be extra-careful looking for any spelling mistakes that pass unnoticed on windows but are lethal on Linux (eg. on Windows test.JPG and test.jpg are the same, on linux these are two different paths!)
2. Press CTRL+0 (zero) to reset zoom level for your domain.
3. Ensure you don't load any additional files and libraries to your website that you don't load (or couldn't load) on localhost.

Answer (score 1):

You may be using fonts that are not "web safe".
Make sure you are using font families as shown [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp). Font families allow each browser to pick a font it's familiar with, but close enough to the original to not affect layout much. There a very few fonts that ALL browsers can render by default. But you can upload your font files to be downloaded by the browser on load if it is very important to use that font. Takes a long time to load the page though. More info on that [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961721/how-do-i-install-a-custom-font-on-an-html-site) I also like using [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator).

Comment: Note that http://www.google.com/webfonts lets you pick a font and only impacts load time by between 10 and 50 ms.

Comment: YES! i forgot about that service.