# Using a font locally stored on Computer, not working

Tags: html, css, fonts

```
                        @font-face {
                            font-family: 'Runescape Chat Font Regular' !important;
                        src:
                            local('Runescape Chat Font Regular'),
                            local('Runescape Chat Font Regular'),
                            url('Runescape Chat Font Regular.ttf');
                        }
```

.

```
                      .message-group.compact .message .message-text .markup .user-name {
                            font-family: 'Runescape Chat Font Regular', sans-serif !important;
                            font-size: 13px !important;
                            font-weight: 100 !important; 
                        }
```

I'm trying to use a font installed on my computer, however its not working. Is there any errors in my code? The Runscape Chat Font Regular font is not being shown. (This is for a group of friends who will all have the font pre-installed, so its okay that the font has to be installed for it to work)

Answer (score 2):

Hi This is how you have to refer the font in css

```
@font-face {
   font-family: myFirstFont;
   src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}
```

Refer this [@font-face rule css](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp)

Refer this to [learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961721/how-do-i-install-a-custom-font-on-an-html-site)