# How would I be able to make emojis work for everyone on my site?

Tags: html, fonts, emoji

I understand that using emojis is terrible for a site, due to some users having some weird setups, but is there any way I can bypass this? Some people who use my site have experienced just a white box instead of an emoji; however, the majority are fine, including myself.

I'd love to use them because they're so easy to handle (at least for me), but I really do not want to use image icons because it's a pain in the butt due to my hosting. Is there some sort of font or something I can use that allows the use of emojis seamlessly on all devices?

Comment: All modern browsers accept unicode In HTML use `&#127744;` to `&#128511;` and for CSS use `\1f300` to `\1f5ff`. When used in HTML it's just like using text. CSS on the other hand is more involved see [**CSS pseudo-elements `::before` and `::after` with `content`**](https://css-tricks.com/css-content/)

Comment: @zer00ne That doesn't solve the problem that the fonts used on some systems may not have the correct glyphs.

Comment: @MichaelMior Did you expect a comment to solve the problem? If this was a solution then I would post it as an answer.

Comment: @zer00ne I was just pointing that out since it may not be obvious to some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use **web fonts**: put the necessary emoji font(s) on your server and use CSS to tell the browser to load them. For details on how to do this, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961721).

Information on free emoji webfonts is available [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31625).