# How can I use fonts which are install in my system to design a webpage using html css?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, fonts

So basically I  have a few fonts installed on my system and I want to use them for my HTML project but when I am changing font-family in CSS I am not able to find that font. So is there any way to use my system fonts? I am trying to use this font here

https://befonts.com/monument-extended-font-family.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961721/how-do-i-install-a-custom-font-on-an-html-site does this solve it?

Comment: yes it did solved it thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at https://www.pagecloud.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-any-website

If you're trying to upload your font at CSS then write like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "YourFont";
  src: url("/fonts/YourFont.woff2") format("woff2"),
       url("/fonts/YourFont.woff") format("woff");
}
```